# Jenkins build stuck after "exit 0" status, and its taking long time to exit from that

Tags: jenkins

I have a few Jenkins build jobs for compiling a .NET application using `npm`, `msbuild`, and unit test case execution steps.

It shows `build success` and hangs after `exit 0 status`, because of that downstream jobs are delayed and failing after long waiting time.

[image]

Is it some process blocking or some plugin issue?

PS: I don't want to use `build-timeout` plugin as the build is already showing success but taking too long to exist from that job.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and added"-DSoftKillWaitSeconds=0" in jenkins.xml before the -jar option. Now jobs execute normally for me. [Link to solution](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55106)