# How to set `killSoftly` for a specific Jenkins job?

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, build, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkins build hangs between build and post-build steps.

The console output shows there is a 6-minute wait (but I've seen waits of up to one hour):

```
10:53:26 BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s
10:53:26 4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
10:53:26 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
10:53:26 Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
11:09:29 [CucumberReport] Using Cucumber Reports version 4.9.0
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039226/jenkins-hangs-between-build-and-post-build) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076004/jenkins-build-stuck-after-exit-0-status-and-its-taking-long-time-to-exit-from) questions that have similar issues, and they say the solution is setting `-DSoftKillWaitSeconds=0` in `jenkins.xml`.

However, I need a way to set the option for particular jobs only, without messing with global Jenkins settings (I wouldn't want to mess with other projects).

**EDIT:**

When I manually abort the job, before the [CucumberReport] step, Cucumber reports are still generated.

I also checked **Abort the build if it's stuck** checkbox in Build Environment options, with Time-out strategy set to `No Activity` (Timeout seconds = 2).

When I build the project with these settings, the build will fail with "Aborted after 0 seconds" shown in Build History, as before, but the console output will be the same. (Nothing changes, Cucumber Reports will be generated but after a certain timeout).

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the parameter? Maybe there is an easier solution for this.

Comment: I want to cut wait time after the build phase. As you can see from the console output, there is a 6-minute wait between build and post-build steps.

Comment: Can you provide some parts of your pipeline? I doubt jenkins is simply stuck - something has to happen here.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what parts of the pipeline would be of interest so I can edit and share some because I'm unable to share actual code?

Comment: Can't you just set a [`timeout`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options) option in your pipe? You should definitely post a simplified version of your pipe. It's hard to "guess" what might be wrong. Also, this question is probably better suited to be at https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tftd I'm new to Jenkins and I'm using a freestyle project so not sure about what do you exactly mean by "pipe".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It  is **not possible to select a job-specific value for `SoftKillWaitSeconds`** (the value is derived from the Jenkins core at a [point](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/d3613f32efaa206eacf23e7198a1c4da4f3f47e3/core/src/main/java/hudson/util/ProcessTree.java#L168) where the job name is not known).

My recommendation is to **fix the abort handling in your job itself**, so it will not depend on a "soft kill timeout". If you're running on a Unix-ish system, you can ensure this by running your job in a new process group (`set -m` in bash) and (for example) setting up a proper exit trap.

Comment: Since I'm new to Jenkins, could you expand on "running your job in a new process group (set -m in bash) and (for example) setting up a proper exit trap"?

Comment: This is unrelated to Jenkins per-se. You can use this approach if your job involves an "Execute shell" build step (or if you can change it so it does). Then use "set -m" to create a new process group, and use a trap like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360201/how-do-i-kill-background-processes-jobs-when-my-shell-script-exits) to ensure that all processes in the group will get killed.

Answer (score 3):

We are using the Build-timeout plugin to kill stuck jobs with timeout strategy set to `No Activity` or `Absolute`. For me, this is a good approach when you are using freestyle projects. 
The reason why your build is "Aborted after 0 seconds" is that most likely there are unfinished child processes.
From [documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timeout):

> Because Java only allows threads to be interrupted at a set of fixed
>   locations, depending on how a build hangs, the abort operation might
>   not take effect. For example,
>
> - **if Jenkins is waiting for child processes to complete, it can abort
>     right away.**
> - if Jenkins is stuck in an infinite loop, it can never be
>     aborted.
> - if Jenkins is doing a network or file I/O within the Java VM
>     (such as lengthy file copy or SVN update), it cannot be aborted.

You could try the absolute timeout strategy. You can define a global variable, so that you do not repeat the timeout value in jobs:

1. Go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System".
2. Check "Environment variables" in "Global properties".
3. Add an environment variable name="GLOBAL_TIMEOUT_MINUTES" value="20".
4. Go to a configuration page of a project.
5. Check "Abort the build if it's stuck" in "Build Environment".
6. Select "Absolute" for "Time-out strategy".    Of course, also applicable to other strategies.
7. Set "${GLOBAL_TIMEOUT_MINUTES}" for "Timeout".
8. Set timeout action "Abort the build".

If this is not working, you could try to look in the logs https://your-jenkins-server/log or in a thread dump.
The hanging may be caused by new/old version of a plugin. Try to find what are the unfinished child processes. Try to disable post-build actions one by one to find the one that may be the cause of the issue.
You can see https://superuser.com/questions/1401879/debugging-what-happens-when-a-jenkins-build-unexpectedly-pauses-or-hangs

Comment: Upvoted for useful info, however, doesn't solve my problem. I already tried build timeout plugin but with no success.